# How to add lodepng.cpp and lodepng.h to my project using DevC++?

Tags: c++

I have wrote this code to which is a simple utility to separate RG/GB Bayer color channels to individual files. It takes in input a RAW12 file and outputs png files corresponding to different Bayer Channels.I tried to compile it using DevC++ and it shows

[Error] lodepng.h: No such file or directory

I'm kinda new to these kind of things, and I don't know how to include lodepng.h and lodepng.cpp in DevC++ I tried a lot to find how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "lodepng.h"`  statement is enough to add the file, if it is present in the same path as the current file in which you are working.

Once you have added the file, you can directly call all the methods in that file or refer to any objects or variables in that file.